Was "Hadji" part of Hadji Murad's name?
Very simple question about the historical figure Hadji Murad (also spelled Murat): was "Hadji" an honorific, indicating that he had made the pilgrimage to Mecca, or was it actually given to him as a first name?
If it was an honorific, do we know when he made the hadj?

While it is common as an honorific, Wikipedia lists loads of people with Hajji as a their given name. It seems that very little is know about Hadji Murad's early life, but I see no evidence to suggest he might have had a different birth name.
